# string column manipulation in Data Frame in pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a string column (Time) in a data frame like this. I want to put underscore between  digits and remove months.

```
Time
2- 3 months          
1- 2 months          
10-11 months          
4- 5 months
 Desired output:
2_3           
1_2           
10_11           
4_5
```

Here is what I am trying but does not seem working.

```
def func(string):
    a_new_string =string.replace('- ','_')
    a_new_string1 =a_new_string.replace('-','_')
    a_new_string2= a_new_string1.rstrip(' months')
    return a_new_string2
```

And applying function to data frame.

```
df['Time'].apply(func)
```

Comment: Are you assigning the result back? `df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(func)`?

Comment: Yes.  I want to apply that function in Time column of data frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use 3 `str` `replace` calls:

```
In [18]:

df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace('- ', '_')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace('-', '_')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace(' months', '')
df
Out[18]:
    Time
0    2_3
1    1_2
2  10_11
3    4_5
```

I think your problem maybe that you're not assigning the result of your `apply` back:

```
In [21]:

def func(string):
    a_new_string =string.replace('- ','_')
    a_new_string1 =a_new_string.replace('-','_')
    a_new_string2= a_new_string1.rstrip(' months')
    return a_new_string2

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(func)
df
Out[21]:
    Time
0    2_3
1    1_2
2  10_11
3    4_5
```

You could also make this a one liner:

```
In [25]:

def func(string):
    return string.replace('- ','_').replace('-','_').rstrip(' months')

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(func)
df
Out[25]:
    Time
0    2_3
1    1_2
2  10_11
3    4_5
```

Comment: I have tried that but I need to use function.  I was trying to write same in function.